# WPF datagrid header rotated by 45 degrees

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm working on releasing my first utility, but I'm having trouble getting the datagrid header to output the way I want.  I'm trying to rotate the datagrid header by 45 degrees so that I can see my whole datagrid on the window.  Currently my datagrid is too large because the header isn't rotated.

Here is a simple rotation but only the text got rotated:

**Initial 45 degree test**
[image]

In my app.xaml I have two other styles that I've already modified to get close (Currently commented out).
The second trial header is very close, but the header gets truncated:

**Test2 - This is the desired arrangement, except for my text and the "lines" getting cut off.**

[image]

I ran a third test where the header is close but the header isn't arranged properly.

**Test3 - Header not arranged properly**
[image]

I created a very simple project for testing.

In the MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DatagridHeaderProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<User> _UserOC;

        public ObservableCollection<User> UserOC
        {
            get { return _UserOC; }
            set { _UserOC = value; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            User User1 = new User(1, "Dave", true, false, true);
            User User2 = new User(2, "Pete", false, true, true);
            User User3 = new User(3, "Mary", false, false, false);
            User User4 = new User(4, "Jane", false, false, true);

            UserOC = new ObservableCollection<User>();
            UserOC.Add(User1);
            UserOC.Add(User2);
            UserOC.Add(User3);
            UserOC.Add(User4);
        }
    }

    public class User
    {

        public User(int id, string name, bool cb1, bool cb2, bool cb3)
        {
            ID = id;
            Name = name;
            CheckBox1 = cb1;
            CheckBox2 = cb2;
            CheckBox3 = cb3;
        }

        private int _ID;
        public int ID
        {
            get { return _ID; }
            set { _ID = value; }
        }
        private string _Name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; }
        }
        private bool _CheckBox1;
        public bool CheckBox1
        {
            get { return _CheckBox1; }
            set { _CheckBox1 = value; }
        }
        private bool _CheckBox2;
        public bool CheckBox2
        {
            get { return _CheckBox2; }
            set { _CheckBox2 = value; }
        }
        private bool _CheckBox3;
        public bool CheckBox3
        {
            get { return _CheckBox3; }
            set { _CheckBox3 = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

In my MainWindow.XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DatagridHeaderProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DatagridHeaderProject"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">


<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding UserOC, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"  Style="{StaticResource DG_Style}" IsReadOnly="True"  SelectionMode="Single"  >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding CheckBox1}" Header="Check Box 1 header is longer"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding CheckBox2}" Header="Check Box 2"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding CheckBox3}" Header="check Box 3"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

In my App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="DatagridHeaderProject.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DatagridHeaderProject"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>


    <Style x:Key="DG_Style" TargetType="DataGrid" >
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="500" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="LightBlue" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{DynamicResource RotatedHeader}"/>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key="RotatedHeader" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" >
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}">
                        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="315" />
                        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>



    <!--This style is very close to what is needed, but the grid width cuts off the text-->
    <!--<Style x:Key="RotatedHeader"  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <DockPanel  Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth}" MinWidth="30" Background="AliceBlue">
                        <Rectangle Name="HeaderRect" Stroke="Black" >
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <SkewTransform CenterX="0" AngleX="-60" AngleY="0" CenterY="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualHeight }"/>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>


                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80">
                            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-30"/>
                            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform  X="20"/>
                            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>-->

    <!--This is close, but the header container is too small so the text gets cut off.-->
    <!--<Style x:Key="RotatedHeader"  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <StackPanel Height="50">
                        <Grid ShowGridLines="True"  Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth}" MinWidth="30" Height ="Auto" Background="AliceBlue" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform AngleX="60"/>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-30"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <Rectangle Name="HeaderRect" Stroke="Black" >
                                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                    <SkewTransform CenterX="0" AngleX="0" AngleY="0" CenterY="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualHeight }"/>
                                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            </Rectangle>


                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80">
                                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform AngleX="-60"/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform X="20"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>-->

</Application.Resources>
```

Any help that you might offer is appreciated.   I am still very new to this, as this is my first real project.

Thank you,

Dave

Comment: "Initial 45 degree test" is a datagrid header rotated by 45 degrees. why do you need others? how do you want to arrange them?

Comment: I would like it to be arranged like the picture shown in Test2, but without my text getting cut off.   This allows the checkboxes to be placed much closer together.  In my actual utility, my datagrid has ~20-30 columns, so I need the headers to be more compact to display everything on the window without having to scroll over